# fetching multiple data with sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a header and line detail table. Such as;

Header table: **`TRANSACTIONS`**
Line detail table: **`TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL`**

In TRANSACTIONS table:
SQ_TRANSACTION_ID, CH_TRANSACTION_NAME,.. columns are included.

In TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL table:
SQ_TRANSACTION_LINE_DETAIL_ID, RF_TRANSACTION_ID, CH_LINE_CODE,.. columns are included.

TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL table keeps one or more detail line for each transactions which kept on TRANSACTIONS table.

So my problem is;

I wanna write a query that fetches me transactions which has X,Y and Z line codes together. (CH_LINE_CODE).

I wrote like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   TR.RF_TRANSACTION_ID
FROM
   TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL TR
WHERE
   TR.CH_LINE_CODE IN ('X','Y','Z')
```

But this code could return me transcations that hasn't got ''Y' or 'X' or 'Z'. I mean i want all line codes included in my transaciton.

I want a query that fetches me transactions that could has

> X, Y, Z

or

> A, B, C, X, Y, Z

or

> X, Y, Z, P

but **NOT**

> X

or

> X, Y

or

> Z, Y, A, B

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this one useful. Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/571ea/3/0).

```
SELECT rf_transaction_id
  FROM transactions_line_detail
 WHERE ch_line_code IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
 GROUP BY rf_transaction_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! that costs much less.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select * From TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL td
Where 
  Exists 
    ( Select 1 From TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL td2
      Where td2.RF_TRANSACTION_ID = td.RF_TRANSACTION_ID
        And td2.CH_LINE_CODE = 'X'
    )
  And 
  Exists 
    ( Select 1 From TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL td2
      Where td2.RF_TRANSACTION_ID = td.RF_TRANSACTION_ID
        And td2.CH_LINE_CODE = 'Y'
    )
  And 
  Exists 
    ( Select 1 From TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL td2
      Where td2.RF_TRANSACTION_ID = td.RF_TRANSACTION_ID
        And td2.CH_LINE_CODE = 'Z'
    )
```